# JS SDK not returning full object, only abbreviation

Tags: parse-platform

I'm upgrading from JS SDK 1.5 to latest.

With SDK 1.5 and earlier I could pass the full Parse Object from one CommonJS controller via the args variable.

```
[DEBUG] :  Found CLUB: {"ACL":{"*":{"read":true},"15QSQgv93Z":{"read":true,"write":true}},"Address":"Atlanta, GA","ApprovalRequired":true,"MemberCount":1,"Name":"The Club Name","Public":true,"createdAt":"2016-02-11T22:01:29.361Z","updatedAt":"2016-02-11T22:01:31.796Z","objectId":"fqMZicTJbK"}
```

But after upgrading (no code changes) I'm only seeing this much

```
[DEBUG] :  ARGS:{"club":{"_objCount":14,"className":"Club","id":"uPB7v2sb7G"}}
undefined is not a function (evaluating 'args.club.get(\"Name\")')
```

As you can see from the source code I am certainly getting the full ParseObject but it's not being received on the other end. Is it being reconstructed or something? I am not familiar with advanced JS.

Source code is here: https://gist.github.com/nitrag/183c2cc15921ab7447f2#file-club_list-js-L30

Thanks for looking